# Nothing in console when running app, but terminal with mongodb shows connection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

The code i have:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sandbox");

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", err => {
  console.error("conection error", err);
});

db.once("Open", () => {
  console.log("Connection Successful");
  // all database communication goes here
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  const AnimalSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    size: String,
    color: String,
    mass: Number,
    name: String
  });

  let Animal = mongoose.model("Animal", AnimalSchema);

  const elephant = new Animal({
    type: "elephant",
    size: "big",
    color: "grey",
    mass: 6000,
    name: "eleanor"
  });

  elephant.save(err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Save Failed");
    } else {
      console.log("Saved!");
    }
    db.close(() => {
      console.log("Connection Closed!");
    });
  });
});
```

When i run this code with mongodb running in the background 
(mongod ran in one terminal window and mongo ran in the other) i don't see anything in the console indicating the app is running(in the code there are logs that should happen, ex: connection successful)

in the terminal where mongo is running i do see this, and it increments every time i run the app.

`I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57449 #2 (2 connections now open)`

Comment: `"Open" != "open"`. It's a typo on the name of the event to listen to. Also remove the `db.close()` since no code here should ever call that. For an *"example"* you could call `mongoose.disconnect()`, but none of your production code need ever disconnect from the database. You keep connections open.

Answer (score 0):

try with on instead of once it's working.
never used once event
`db.on("open", () => {
  console.log("Connection Successful");
});`

Comment: Nothing :/ i only used once because i'm following along with a video (i'm new to this) and thats what the person used

Comment: not sure about that tried with once but it didn't worked 
but with on it's working